# UIAlertView with a user supplied context and [self autorelease]

Tags: objective-c, ios, uialertview

I have looked over some ideas for how to supply a context to a UIAlertView. The common answers are save it in a dictionary or subclass UIAlertView. I don't like the idea of saving the context in a dictionary, it's the wrong place for the data. Subclassing UIAlertView is not supported by Apple, so by my standard, is not a good solution.

I came up with an idea, but I'm not sure what to make of it. Create an instance of a context object that is the delegate of UIAlertView. The alert view context, in turn, has it's own delegate which is the view controller.

The trouble is releasing memory. I set alertView.delegate to nil and call [self autorelease] to free the context object in -alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:.

**THE QUESTION IS**: What problems am I causing myself? I have a suspicion that I'm setting myself up for a subtle memory error.

Here is the simple version which only supports -alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:

#### Use

```
- (void)askUserIfTheyWantToSeeRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    [[[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:[userInfo valueForKey:@"action"]
                                 message:[userInfo valueForKeyPath:@"aps.alert"]
                                delegate:[[WantAlertViewContext alloc] initWithDelegate:self context:userInfo]
                       cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss"
                       otherButtonTitles:@"View", nil] autorelease] show];
}
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex withContext:(id)context
{
    if (buttonIndex != alertView.cancelButtonIndex)
        [self presentViewForRemoteNotification:context];
}
```

#### Interface

```
@protocol WantAlertViewContextDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex withContext:(id)context;
@end

@interface WantAlertViewContext : NSObject <UIAlertViewDelegate>
- (id)initWithDelegate:(id<WantAlertViewContextDelegate>)delegate context:(id)context;
@property (assign, nonatomic) id<WantAlertViewContextDelegate> delegate;
@property (retain, nonatomic) id context;
@end
```

#### Implementation

```
@implementation WantAlertViewContext
- (id)initWithDelegate:(id<WantAlertViewContextDelegate>)delegate context:(id)context
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _delegate = delegate;
        _context  = [context retain];
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)dealloc
{
    [_context release];
    [super dealloc];
}
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    [self.delegate alertView:alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:buttonIndex withContext:self.context];
}
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    alertView.delegate = nil;
    [self autorelease];
}
@synthesize delegate = _delegate;
@synthesize context  = _context;
@end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the concept of associated objects. Using the functions `objc_setAssociatedObject()` and `objc_getAssociatedObject()`. You can use these properties to essentially add a new property, in your case to hold an `NSDictionary`, to an object through a category.

Here is an example of a `UIAlertView` category. These files should be compiled without `ARC`, `-fno-objc-arc` flag set if the project is using ARC.

**UIAlertView+WithContext.h:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface UIAlertView (Context)
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSDictionary *userInfo;
@end
```

**UIAlertView+WithContext.m:**

```
#import "UIAlertView+WithContext.h"
// This enum is actually declared elseware
enum {
    OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN = 0,
    OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC = 1,
    OBJC_ASSOCIATION_COPY_NONATOMIC = 3,
    OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN = 01401,
    OBJC_ASSOCIATION_COPY = 01403
};
@implementation UIAlertView (Context) 
static char ContextPrivateKey;
-(void)setUserInfo:(NSDictionary *)userInfo{
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &ContextPrivateKey, userInfo, 3);
}
-(NSDictionary *)userInfo{
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &ContextPrivateKey);
}
@end
```

This category is easily used.

**SomeViewController.m:** a `UIAlertViewDelegate` using ARC or not.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    alert.userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"Hello" forKey:@"Greeting"];// autorelease if MRC
    [alert show]; // release if MRC
}

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    NSLog(@"userInfo:%@",alertView.userInfo);
}
```

When you press the alertview's OK button you will see:

```
userInfo:{
    Greeting = Hello;
}
```

A couple of notes:

1) Make sure the association type matches the property declaration so things behave as expected.

2) You probably shouldn't use `userInfo` for the property/association since Apple may well decide to add a `userInfo` property to `UIAlertView` in the future.

**Edit** *To address your concerns about your `[self autorelease];`*

It is imperative that you balance your implicit `alloc` retain from this line: `delegate:[[WantAlertViewContext alloc] initWithDelegate:self context:userInfo]`. You achieve this balance by calling `[self autorelease];` in the final `UIAlertView` delegate method.

Granted, this does feel wrong. Mostly because there is no way when looking at this that it doesn't at first blush look like memory mis-management. But there is one simple way to avoid this "controlled leak" API you are creating; Have the instance of `WantAlertViewContext` explicitly retain itself. For example:

```
-(id)initWithDelegate:(id<WantAlertViewContextDelegate>)delegate context:(id)context{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _delegate = delegate;
        _context  = [context retain];
    }
    return [self retain]; // Explicitly retain self
}

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    alertView.delegate = nil;
    [self autorelease]; // Or just [self release]; doesn't make much difference at this point
}
```

Now your class has some internal harmony. I say some because this is still not perfect. For example, if an instance is never an alert-view delegate it will never be released. It is still just a "semi-controlled" memory leak.

Anyway, now your instantiation call can look more logical:

```
delegate:[[[WantAlertViewContext alloc] initWithDelegate:self context:userInfo] autorelease];
```

I think that this particular design pattern is fraught with danger. If you do end up using it keep a close eye on it.

Comment: I like the idea and may switch over to it, but it doesn't exactly answer my [self autorelease] question. I think I would feel a whole lot better if I got rid of this [self autorelease].

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the response and the elaboration. I was thinking something along the same lines. I just wanted to make sure I wasn't fooling myself. I've caused a fair number of tricky memory issues by being too clever. I think it's a bit of a moot point, because I'm switching over to associated objects. It is nice to know that [self release] and [self autorelease] are useful, albeit dangerous, tools.

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with a simpler solution that may fit in some circumstances. Because you get the NSAlertView context when the delegate gets called, I use the actual address of the object to make a tag (NSString*) which I then use to store custom values in a global or object specific NSDictionary. Here is an example:

```
+(NSString*)GetTag:(id)ObjectIn
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Tag-%i",(int)ObjectIn];
}
```

In the Delegate:

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSString* MyID = [CommandManager GetTag:alertView];
    [CurrentActiveAlerts removeObjectForKey:MyID];
}
```

Calling:

```
UIAlertView *myAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title_text
                                                          message:@""
                                                     delegate:self
                                            cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                        otherButtonTitles:button_text ,nil];

    CurrentActiveAlerts[[CommandManager GetTag:myAlert]] = CommandToRun;        // Querky way to link NSDict to UIAlert, but the best I could think of
    [myAlert show];
    [myAlert release];
```

The keys will end up looking like "Tag-226811776". Hope this helps.