# objc_setAssociatedObject crash (iOS7+64 bit) workaround

Tags: objective-c, ios7, 64-bit

Using the following code in a `NSDate` category, I get a **EXC_BAD_ACCESS_(code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)** crash error whenever the type of the `NSDate` is actually `__NSTaggedDate`:

```
objc_setAssociatedObject(self, MyKey, myValue, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
```

How I understand [the information I read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21561211/objc-setassociatedobject-function-error-in-64bit-mode-not-in-32bit), this is a known issue caused by an Apple bug which shows up under iOS7 on 64 bit systems only.

I am looking for a workaround.

Comment: They have given a possible workaround in the link you have mentioned. Have you explored those options Update (possible solution/workaround): The "SKSTableView" project (link at the end of the question) uses a category on NSIndexPath and associated objects to add a third property "subrow" to an index path.

Comment: Thanks. We ended up using _NSMapTable_ like mentioned in the link. I was hoping to find a workaround to keep on using _AssociatedObject_. Somthing like getting the actual NSDate somehow.